# Read in file line by line and search another file for a line with a partial match

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, grep

I have a file with partial matches to lines in another file. In order to do this I was looking to generate a while loop with read and substituting a variable for each line of partial matches into a grep command to search a database files with a partial match but for some reason, I am not getting an output (an empty outputfile.txt).

Here is my current script

```
while read -r line; do
    grep $line /path/to/databasefile >> /path/to/folder/outputfile.txt
done < "/partial_matches.txt"
```

the database has multiple lines with a sequence name then DNA sequence after:

```
 >transcript_ab
 AGTCAGTCATGTC
 >transcript_ac
 AGTCAGTCATGTC
 >transctipt_ad
 AGTCAGTCATGTC
```

and the partial matching search file has lines of text:

```
 ab
 ac
```

and I'm looking for a return of:

```
 >transcript_ab
 >transcript_ac
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So `/outputfile.txt` is empty? (P.S. how are you writing to `/`? are you running this as root?!)

Comment: @RobinGreen yeah the outputfile.txt is empty and I just didn't include the path to the file, however I editted and clarified up in the question

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the file?

Comment: @RobinGreen yes it is in my user directory

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean you have permission to write to it. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GNU `grep`, then its `-f` option is what you are looking for:

```
grep -f /partial_matches.txt /path/to/databasefile
```

(if you don't have any pattern in partial_matches.txt but only strings, then use `grep -F` instead of `grep`)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a for loop instead:

```
for i in $(cat partial_matches.txt); do
grep $i /path/to/databasefile >> /path/to/folder/outputfile.txt
done
```

Also, check if you have a typo:
`"/partial_matches.txt"` -> `"./partial_matches.txt"`